# Copy Files quickly from a mapped network drive

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, mapping

Can anyone tell me how to quickly copy Files from a mapped network drive?

The windows Copy Paste works very slow and hampers the performance of the system.

I have used XCOPY source destination /i /s /z /q

This was quick enough and copied a few files and later threw an error "The specified network name not available"

I remember somebody using a workaround to copy files quickly from mapped networked drive.

Can any one suggest me a way to do this?

I use Windows XP, so please don't suggest me RoboCopy.

Comment: I have the same problem but with windows 2000. I hope someone will answer...

Comment: You can install robocopy on Windows XP and it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RoboCopy works fine on WinXP. The Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit that contains RoboCopy installs fine on XP.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable, fast and simple way to copy files between Windows computers using only the tools that come with the OS.

Your options are:

- [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)
- RoboCopy (See this [article with instructions](http://theos.in/windows-server/free-download-windows-xp-2003-robocopy-software/) on XP)
- rsync (comes with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/))

Note that you can download the Windows 2003 server tools and unpack them on XP. It will work on XP.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com) is **significantly** faster than any of the built-in copy mechanisms, including when copying files over the network.

Answer (score 0):

use Ipmessanger I can copy at 55 MB /Sec (SATA2 7200 RPMS HDD on both PC's) on my Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: Can you provide a link ? (I think there is a typo in the name)